# MCD19A2: Alternative to masking with quality property that does not create zeros in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Third Edit: The only reason I can think of for my exported zeros is that MCD19A2 reports some missings as zero, but gives them a "Best Quality" value in the AOD_QA band. This means for many regions all pixels get masked out, but some zero measurements stay. Is that plausible?

---

Second edit: The behavior of .mean() functions is explained in the official tutorials, e.g. here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region. They do not take into account pixels that are masked out.

---

First Edit: I'm wondering now whether it is default behavior of `ee.Reducer.mean()` to return zero if all pixels are missing. I haven't found anything on this in the documentation. Can anybody confirm this?

---

I'm creating daily pollution averages by ROI with MCD19A2_GRANULES and I want to filter out low quality images. Currently, I'm doing this with a mask, but I get  zeros rather than missings after I take the `mean()` of the daily `ImageCollection` and after applying the `ReduceRegions` to these daily means. I assume that this is due to the mask creating zeros in the band.

Would it make sense to do a `.filter(ee.Filter.neq('Optical_Depth_047', 0))` in Line 69 after I map my `filterBadObs` function over the ImageCollection? The problem is that this would also filter out true zeros.

What would be a better way to filter here?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/93d347f272c81105144c0afff82da125

Answer (score 0):

My code stopped returning zeros, when I started masking with `.updateMask()` rather than `.mask()`. It seems that pixels masked by the latter are not excluded but counted as zeros in `.mean()` functions.